# Reading from a python file

Tags: python

I have a text file that got some antonyms in the format:

> able || unable
>   unable || able
>   abaxial || adaxial
>   adaxial || abaxial

and I need to check if this word is antonyms of another or not.

What i did is a code like this:

```
def antonyms():
    f = open('antonyms.txt', 'r+')
    for line in f:
        a = line.split('||')
        x = a[0]
        y = a[1]
    return x, y
```

but what I have got is only the last pairs, then I tried to indent return a bit so I did

```
def antonyms():
    f = open('antonym_adjectives.txt', 'r+')
    for line in f:
        a = line.split('||')
        x = a[0]
        y = a[1]
        return x, y
```

But again I got first pairs only

How can I get all of the pairs?

and how can I do something like:

```
>>> antonyms(x, y)
```

to tell me if they are True or False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because no answer answers BOTH your questions:

Firstly: if you return, the program will stop there. So you want to `yield` your antonym so the whole function becomes a generator:

```
def antonyms():
    f = open('antonyms.txt', 'r+')
    for line in f:
        a = line.split(' || ') # Think you also need surrounding spaces here.
        x = a[0]
        y = a[1]
        yield x, y
```

To use this function to check for `is_antonym(a,b)`:

```
def is_antonym(a,b):
    for x,y in antonyms():
        if a == x and b == y:
            return True
    return False
```

Other answers have good tips too: 
A good replacement for instance would be: `[x,y] = line.split(' || ')`

Comment: Thanks Ruben for suggesting editing the question :) and thanks for your suggestion of the space surrounding, you are right.

I will try this

Comment: Wouldn't you also want to check for `b == x and a == y`?

Comment: Looking at the way his file is structured: no, but if he'd change that then it would be a good thing.

Comment: Do you know why some words end up with \n ?  like in  ('unmalted ', ' malted\n'), ('posed ', ' unposed\n'), ('unposed ', ' posed\n'), ('saponified ', ' unsaponified\n'), ('unsaponified ', ' saponified')

while they are not like that in actual .txt file?

Comment: oh that's because `\n` is the return at the end of the line.
you can remove them if you edit it to: `line.rstrip().split(' || ')`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that with `return` you are getting out of the function.

Instead, of `x = a[0]` and `y = a[1]`, append those values to an array, and the return that array.

```
the_array = []
for line in f:
    a = line.split('||')
    the_array.append((a[0],a[1]))
return the_array
```

Comment: it gave me the first pair this one

Comment: @user3633694 impossible. Just tested. Check where are you placing the return, indentation is very important in Python :) the `for` and the `return` must be at the same level.

Comment: Sorry, you're right it might be the problem of locating RETURN then, I did it again and it works. Thank you very much, nice answer, easy to understand. Vote Up

Comment: some words appear like this

 ('unmalted ', ' malted\n'), ('posed ', ' unposed\n'), ('unposed ', ' posed\n'), ('saponified ', ' unsaponified\n'), ('unsaponified ', ' saponified')

why there is \n do you think?

Comment: @user3633694 that '\n' is the character that make it possible to jump to a next line in a file. You can remove them using for example `rstrip`, or if instead of just `print the_array` you do something like `for pair in the_array: print pair[0], pair[1]` they will not show up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use yield:

```
def antonyms():
    f = open('antonyms.txt', 'r+')
    for line in f:
        a = line.split('||')
        x = a[0]
        y = a[1]
        yield x, y

for a,b in antonyms():
     # rest of code here
```

By the way, you can assign directly to x and y:

```
x,y = line.split('||')
```

A simple check if a and b are antonyms could be:

```
(a == 'un' + b) or (b == 'un' + a)
```

Comment: A great command (yield).
I like the way that you explain it without changing my thoughts and understanding of the code.

how to check if one is antonym of another.

Comment: I like your approach to the problem and I'd like to upvote, but I wonder if the OP can appreciate it w/o some word of explanation on your part...

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the problem of working out whether a given pair of words are antonyms.

Comment: I like your answer as well. Thanks elzell

Great answer. helpful hints

Comment: @user3633694 Yield is a way to return a value from a function and continuing at the same point, then returning the next value, so to say (technically speaking: to create a generator rather than a function)... normally you leave a function at a return.

Comment: Great way to run away from return 

return (sometimes) cause a headache

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to write a function that gets the antonym of a given word:

```
def antonym(word):
    with open('antonym_adjectives.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            a, b = line.split('||')
            a = a.strip()
            b = b.strip()
            if a == word:
                return b
            if b == word:
                return a
```

You can then write `antonym(x) == y` to check if `x` and `y` are antonyms. (However this assumes each word has a single unique antonym).

This reads the file from the beginning each time. If your list of antonyms is manageable in size it might make more sense to read it in to memory as an array or dictionary.

If you can't assume that each word has a single unique antonym, you could turn this into a generator that will return all the antonyms for a given word.

```
def antonym(word):
    with open('antonym_adjectives.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            a, b = line.split('||')
            a = a.strip()
            b = b.strip()
            if a == word:
                yield b
            if b == word:
                yield a
```

Then `y in antonyms(x)` will tell you whether `x` and `y` are antonyms, and `list(antonyms(x))` will give you the list of all the antonyms of `x`.

Comment: This will open and read the file every time you want to check an antonym.  This may "make more sense" under some conditions, but we don't have enough information about the OP's application to draw such a conclusion.  It very well might make more sense to construct a `dict` of antonyms.

Comment: @saulspatz Like I said in my response.

Comment: You are right (saulspatz) I was thinking of making a dict but I am not that good programmer, so this will work. 

Stuart, it is good way, but some words might have more then one antonym as you said.

Comment: @Stuart Right you are, I seem to have overlooked that.  I shouldn't do this before my morning caffein.

Answer (score 0):

that is my code ..

```
def antonyms(first,second):
    f = open('text.txt', 'r')

    for line in f.readlines():
        lst = [s.strip() for s in line.split('||')]
        if lst and len(lst) == 2:
            x = lst[0]
            y = lst[1]
            if first == x and second == y:
                return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think list is a good data structure for this problem.  After you've read all the antonym pairs into a list, you still have to search the whole list to find the antonym of a word.  A dict would be more efficient.

```
antonym = {}
with open('antonym_adjectives.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
       x,y = line.split('||)
       antonym[x] = y
       antonym[y] = x
```

Now you can just look up an antonym in the dict:

```
try:
   opposite = antonym[word]
except KeyError:
   print("%s not found" %word)
```